# How to toggle between two images with a button using Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle, addeventlistener

I have an HTML document that has an image, and I want to click a button to 
toggle between the color version and the black & white version. My 
javascript code is as follows is below. I realize this question has been 
answered before, but the answers were unclear. Questions: Is the IF condition valid? If not, what can I use? Can one compare an image.src with an address on my computer as typed below? Note that nothing is changing when I click. The color image remains.

```
let colorImage = document.getElementById("colorImage");
let button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

function changeToBW() {

    if (colorImage.src == "Rondout.jpg") {    // I tried three === but that 
                                              // didn't work either.
        colorImage.src = "Rondout(B&W).jpg";
}
    else {
        colorImage.src = "Rondout.jpg";
}
}
 button2.addEventListener("click", changeToBW);
```

A portion of my HTML code that's within the body below:

```
<img id = "colorImage" class = "image" src = "Rondout.jpg">
    <button id = "button2" type = "button">Change to B&W</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code to see where the problem is. I used 2 imgs that i just downloaded form google: img1.png and img2.jpeg

It didn't worked. So I opened the DevTab of Google Chrome.

So my code:

```
let colorImage = document.getElementById("colorImage");
let button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

function changeToBW() {

    if (colorImage.src == "img1.png") { // colorImage.src = file:///D:/Kokal/Code/JsTests/img1.png

        colorImage.src = "img2.jpeg";
    }
    else {
        colorImage.src = "img1.png";
    }
}

button2.addEventListener("click", changeToBW);
```

The problem is that `colorImage.src` holds the absolute path to the file. So you never end-up in the `if` you aways go in the `else`.

Also you want to change the attribute src not the property. So you need to read the attr too. The way to do it is with the function `getAttribute('src')` on the `colorImage`.
After that you will need to set that attr with `setAttribute('src', [new value])`

If something is not clear chek my code below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img id = "colorImage" class = "image" src = "./img1.png">
    <button id = "button2" type = "button">Change to B&W</button>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let colorImage = document.getElementById("colorImage");
let button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

function changeToBW() {

    if (colorImage.getAttribute('src') === "./img1.png") {
        colorImage.setAttribute('src', "./img2.jpg");
    }
    else {
        colorImage.setAttribute('src', "./img1.png");
    }
}

button2.addEventListener("click", changeToBW);
```

Comment: You're a genius. Thanks! I'm curious what the ./ in the src attribute is for?

Comment: With ./ you telling the path to start from the root folder of the project. This makes the path relative. Otherways your path is absolute and you need to puth the hole path to the file like 'D:\Some folder\SomeOtherFolder\yourFile.jpg'.

Comment: In the your code you use `==`. I recomend to you to use `===`! The difference is that `==` is not strict. What that means. Well `"3" == 3 // true` and `"3" === 3 // false`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to keep track of which image is displayed.

In my example, I use the data attribute `data-color` for this.

Then in the onClick handler, I get the `data-color` value and toggle between the 0 and 1. The 1 and 0 then correspond with the index in the array images. Which is added to the `src` of `colorImage`.

Here's a working example.

```js
let colorImage = document.getElementById("colorImage");
let button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

function changeToBW() {
  var images = [
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/57905/pexels-photo-57905.jpeg",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/56866/garden-rose-red-pink-56866.jpeg"
  ];
  var imageNum = parseInt(colorImage.dataset.color);
  var nextImg = imageNum === 0 ? 1 : 0;
  colorImage.src = images[nextImg];
  colorImage.dataset.color = nextImg;
}
button2.addEventListener("click", changeToBW);
```

```html
<img id="colorImage" data-color="0" class="image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/57905/pexels-photo-57905.jpeg" width="200">
<div><button id="button2" type="button">Change to B&W</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let colorImage = document.getElementById("colorImage");

let button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

let imgFlag = 1;

function changeToBW() {

    if (imgFlag) {
        colorImage.setAttribute('src', "./img2.jpg");
        ImgFlag = 0;
    }
    else {
        colorImage.setAttribute('src', "./img1.png");
        ImgFlag = 1;
    }
}

button2.addEventListener("toggle", changeToBW);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following code after creating html and css files to switch between two pictures and adding two buttons:

```
const image = document.getElementById("image");
const btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

btn1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    image.src = "image1.jpg";
});

btn2.addEventListener("click", () => {
    image.src = "image2.jpg";
});
```